# How do I send image ids from cloudinary to my MongoDB database

Tags: mongodb, post, next.js13, cloudinary

So I have been trying to send the public id of my images that i upload to cloudinary to my mongodb database but i am unable to find it in my browse collection despite the fact i can not find any errors in the code. i am trying to build the admin panel of an ecommerce app and so far i have succeeded in generating the price,title and description dynamically but not the image

This is the ProductForm

```
"use client"
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";
import { useState } from "react";
import UploadButton from "./UploadButton";

export default function ProductsForm({
  id,
  title: Atitle,
  description: Adescription,
  price: Aprice=[],
  
}) {
  const [title, setTitle] = useState(Atitle || "");
  const [description, setDescription] = useState(Adescription || "");
  const [price, setPrice] = useState(Aprice || "");

  const [imageid, setImageid] = useState([]);
  
  const display = (result) => {
    // Append the new image public_id to the existing array of image IDs
    setImageid((prevImage) => [...prevImage, result.info.public_id]);
  };

  const router = useRouter();

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (!title || !price) {
      alert("Title and Price are required");
      return;
    }

    try {
      if (id) {
        // Use a PUT request to update an existing product
        const res = await fetch(`/api/Products/${id}`, {
          method: "PUT",
          headers: {
            "Content-type": "application/json",
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
            newTitle: title,
            newDescription: description,
            newPrice: price,
            imageid
          }),
        });

        if (!res.ok) {
          throw new Error("Failed to update product");
        } 
        router.refresh();
        router.push("/products");
        
      } else {
        // Use a POST request to create a new product
        const res = await fetch("/api/Products", {
          method: "POST",
          headers: {
            "Content-type": "application/json",
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({ title, description, price, imageid }),
        });

        if (res.ok) {
          router.push("/products");
        } else {
          throw new Error("Failed to create new Product");
        }
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="p-5 w-full h-screen">
      <form action="" onSubmit={handleSubmit} className="flex flex-col">
        <label htmlFor="">Product</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          className="w-full sm:w-1/2"
          placeholder="New Products"
          value={title}
          onChange={(e) => setTitle(e.target.value)}
        />

        <UploadButton display={display} imageid={imageid}/>
        <label htmlFor="">Product Description</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          className="w-full sm:w-1/2 py-3"
          placeholder="Description"
          value={description}
          onChange={(e) => setDescription(e.target.value)}
        />
        <label htmlFor="">Price in Naira</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          className="w-full sm:w-1/2 py-3"
          placeholder="Price"
          value={price}
          onChange={(e) => setPrice(e.target.value)}
        />

        <button type="submit" className="btn mt-2">
          Save
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

This is the image submission component

```
"use client"
import { CldImage, CldUploadButton } from "next-cloudinary"
import { useState } from "react"

const UploadButton = ({imageid,display}) => {
   
  
    return (
      <main className="rounded mt-3 border flex w-full flex-col">
        <CldUploadButton
          onUpload={display}
          className="w-20 h-7 rounded bg-gray-300"
          uploadPreset="zp35znzb"
          
        />

       <div className="flex flex-wrap">
       {imageid.map((public_id, index) => (
          <div className="m-2"><CldImage
            key={index}
            src={public_id}
            alt={`Uploaded Image ${index + 1}`}
            width="150"
            height="150"
            className="flex"
          /></div>
        ))}
       </div>
      </main>
    );
  };
  
  export default UploadButton;
```

My POST request

```
export async function POST(req){
   /* const body = await req.json()*/
    const {title,description,price,imageid} = await req.json()// if first line dont work replace and do same in rest of code
    console.log({title,description,price,imageid})
    await ConnectMongoDB();
    await Product.create({title,description,price,imageid});
    console.log({title,description,price,imageid})
    /*await Product.create({ title: req.body.title, description: req.body.description, price: req.body.price, imageid: req.body.imageid.split(",") });*/
    return NextResponse.json({message:"Product Registered"},{status:201})

}
```

Comment: If you `console.log({title,description,price,imageid})` at that start of your POST, what is the output? Also, do you get if you `console.log(JSON.stringify({newTitle: title, newDescription: description, newPrice: price, imageid}))` from your ProductForm?